# Assets dialog customization

Tags: magnolia

this is a case for Magnolia CMS

1. Press "Edit Asset" within assets area
2. Press Add Tag button
3. Press "Select new" button
4. From opened dialog select more than one Category
5. Press "Choose" button

As a result only one Category will be choosen.

Is there any way to save a set of the selected Tags from assets dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just add a field for category into asset dialog.

See https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Dialog+definition for details about the dialog and how to add fields to it.

The one you are looking for in particular is to be found under Configuration under path `/modules/dam-app/apps/assets/subApps/detail/editor/form/tabs/asset/fields`

HTH,
Jan